# testPathIgnorePatterns doesn't seem to work

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following `jest.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        "js",
        "json",
        "ts"
    ],
    rootDir: ".",
    testRegex: ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    testEnvironment: "node",
    roots: [
        "<rootDir>/tests/"
    ],
    reporters: [
        'default',
        [
            'jest-junit',
            {
                traitsRegex: [
                    { regex: /\(Test Type:([^,)]+)(,|\)).*/g, name: 'Category' },
                    { regex: /.*Test Traits: ([^)]+)\).*/g, name: 'Type' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^@test/fixtures(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/fixtures/$1",
        "^@test/utils(|/.*)$": "<rootDir>/utils/$1",
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-extended/all"],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '/node_modules/',
        '<rootDir>/tests/to-ignore/'
    ]
};
```

However, when I run `npm test -c jest.config.js`, I am getting, amongst other test files:

```
 RUNS  tests/to-ignore/test.spec.ts
```

I do not want the file above to be executed.

I also tried a few different ways to specify `testPathIgnorePatterns`:

- `to-ignore`
- `<rootDir>\/tests\/to-ignore`

None of them work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `'<rootDir>/to-ignore/'` since your root is defined as:
`roots: ["<rootDir>/tests/"]`